# How to set array of controls to placeholder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am a beginner with asp.net 
I'm doing a image retrieval project , in the end i have images links
now , i create image control, give it the link and add to the placeholder
but it give me error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

code :

```
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image [] result = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image[links.Count()];

  for (int h = 0; h < result.Length; h++)
    {     
       result[h].ImageUrl = links[h];  /// here's the error 
       PlaceHolder1.Controls.AddAt(h, result[h]);    
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate the Image in each array index before assigning to a member in it. try:

```
result[h] = new Image() { ImageUrl = links[h] };
```